# add toast when we first launch application

Tags: android

Is there any method that after installing application in android device when I first launch the application it will show me a toast.
And after that whenever I launch the app it won't show that toast.
Thnks in advance. :)

Comment: put the code of showing toast in an "if" condition with a static variable assigned 'true' already and after showing the toast, make that variable false and then never make it true.

Answer (score 2):

Add a variable to ClientPreferences that you set to true if the user has opened the application. You can then in onCreate in your main activity show the Toast if that variable is false.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences(
        "com.your.app", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean hasVisisted = prefs.getBoolean("HAS_VISISTED_BEFORE", false);
if(!hasVisited) {
    Toast.makeText(...).show();
    prefs.edit().putBoolean("HAS_VISISTED_BEFORE", true).commit();
}
```

Comment: Instead of using a boolean, I prefer to make such a value numeric and representative of the version of the application. This way when an upgrade is installed, I can tell that they've had the application before but it is now newer, and I can present release notes (custom to the new changes), etc.

Comment: thnks jelgh..it helps a lot!!

Comment: You might want to check this question done if you feel that it gave you what you wanted :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have to save somewhere a value which you can check on each startup whether the app was already started.  [SharePreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) would be a option. Or within a database.

Answer (score 0):

Use SharedPreference to save value even if application is closed.

so when your application starts first time check that shared preference value, and make toast and change the value of shared preference.
now when finishing the app, change value of shared preference.

you can refere [this link](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html)

hope this will help you.